# How to show the current category of an article with CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a question about CPT UI, i would like to show the category of the article please,

```
     <?php     
            $args= array('post_type'=>'formation', 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=> 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 9);
            $loop= new WP_Query($args);$i=0;
            if ( $loop-> have_posts() ) : while ( $loop-> have_posts() ) : $loop-> the_post();  
        ?>


<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>         
        <div class="news-container">

             <div class="img-news" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">

            <div class="filtre-news"></div>


             </div>

            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>



           </div>


            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

My custom post type name is : formation and the taxomonie is promo..

Thank you every one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to retrieve the terms of a specific taxonomy of each post. You can use this inside the loop:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'promo' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

get_the_terms returns an array of terms and each term has the following properties:

```
WP_Term Object
(
[term_id] =>
[name] =>
[slug] =>
[term_group] =>
[term_taxonomy_id] =>
[taxonomy] =>
[description] =>
[parent] =>
[count] =>
[filter] =>
)
```